# REQUEST_URI vs HTACCESS

Tags: php, routes

As far as I am aware there are two different ways of 'routing' and using 'friendly urls'

1: Solely using .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^foobar/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ "index.php?foo=$1&bar=$2" [NC]
```

or
2: Using .htaccess in conjunction with an index.php 'routing' system:

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
          RewriteEngine On
          RewriteBase /
          # if file not exists
          RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
          # if dir not exists
          RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
          # avoid 404s of missing assets in our script
          RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*\.(jpe?g|png|gif|css|js)$ [NC]
          RewriteRule .* index.php [QSA,L]
    </IfModule>
```

And then inside index.php:

```
$uri = explode("/",substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],1));
    if((isset($uri[0])) && ($uri[0]!="")) {
        $page = $uri[0];
        if(is_file(ROOT."/subs/docs/$page/config.php")) {
               include(ROOT."/subs/docs/$page/config.php");
            }
    } else {
        $page="home";
    }
```

then include $page somewhere down the line.

My question is, which way is better, or is there some other method I am unaware of? And by better I mean in terms of efficiency, speed, and logic.

Comment: Does it matter to you which is more efficient?

Comment: Another method which sort of mixes the two would be a front controller, where all %{REQUEST_URI}s are routed to a single file, which then pulls the $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] to pieces to find out which PHP classes would deal with the URL. Whether it's more efficient or not, I don't know. Personally I find it easier to put the logic in PHP than in the .htaccess, but this is just personal

Comment: Just heads up, the code you're showing is quite dangerous and fairly easy to exploit.

Comment: @GarethL that is exactly what I am doing! :D

Comment: @KarlLaurentiusRoos In what way is it easy to exploit?

Comment: @Chud37, since `$page` is a variable, I can introduce `$page` to be `../../etc/passwd` and so on. There is a special character that I can append which can make PHP ignore `/config.php`. You need to do some checking so that people can't do directory traversals :)

Comment: @F21, any advice as to where I could read up on what your talking about? I am very interested in securing things!

Comment: @Chud37: This is a good start: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4205278/624884 Also, google for "php directory traversal" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the real life most routing systems are so complicated that 1st option turns `.htaccess` right into living nightmare.

As a matter of fact, the number of all possible input parameters combinations as so huge, that main application router have to deal only with detecting controller. While each particular controller have to deal with them it's own way.
Frankly, you cannot tell for sure that 2nd parameter have to be assigned to the foo variable and 3rd assigned to the bar.

So, there is no choice but 2nd one.

Comment: That's a good point.  So is the second one the *best* way to do it, in your opinion? Or what is?