# Is dirname adequate to prevent directory traversal attacks?

Tags: php, security, encoding, url-parameters, directory-traversal

Consider the following classic problem case:

```
<?php
$filename = "/tmp/".$_GET['f'];
readfile($filename);
```

This code is vulnerable to a [directory traversal attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_traversal_attack), for example if the value of `$_GET['f']` is `../etc/shadow` the contents of that file will be disclosed to the attacker.

There are well-known approaches to prevent this type of attack; I am not asking how to do that. The question is: **is the following use of [`dirname`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php) a bulletproof way to prevent the attack?**

```
<?php
if (dirname($_GET['f']) != '.') die ('Attack prevented');
```

It *sounds* like it should be since `dirname`:

- returns `.` if and only if there are no slashes in the input path (the online documentation makes a less rigorous guarantee but [the source](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_5/Zend/zend_compile.c#7128) is explicit)
- is binary-safe (so cannot be tricked by embedded nulls)

So as far as I can tell, the only possible avenue of attack would be to pass data to `$_GET['f']` in an encoding such that either the character `/` or `\` (let's not forget Windows) encodes to something that does *not* contain the ASCII value of the corresponding character *and* at the same time this encoding has to be transparently supported by the underlying C runtime library's `fopen` function.

The no-ASCII-value restriction rules out all single-byte encodings, UTF-8, and both flavors of UTF-16; furthermore, since the spec for the C runtime is platform-agnostic the attack could only be applicable to some filesystem that used a "vulnerable" encoding to represent names. Such a filesystem does not, to my knowledge, exist; it would hardly make sense for anyone to create it; and finally PHP would not be hosted on such a hypothetical exotic system even if it existed.

In conclusion, it seems to me that this check *is* 100% safe. Is there something I missed?

Comment: I have used the code from this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4205278/453348) also you can check the `MainMa` answer from that question

Comment: @tttony: Thanks, but as I say above I know how to prevent the attack. The question is, can it be confidently prevented *this way*?

Comment: According to my test, your method works, look simple but it works

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I'd ever make the claim that something is 100% safe. That said, I can't think of an obvious case where this would be unsafe and I tried a ton of permutations against it. That said, you'll want to add a check that $_GET['f'] isn't empty in there. Visiting a page with the above code with no value for f gave me the "Attack prevented" message, which is probably not the desired effect.

```
<?php
if (!empty($_GET['f']) && dirname($_GET['f']) != '.') die ('Attack prevented');
```

Comment: Sure, the examples contain the bare minimum code to illustrate. What kind of permutations did you try?

Comment: I created a file 1 level up and typed in every conceivable way I could think of to reference that file (i.e. ?f=../test.txt ?f=..\test.txt ?f=..%2Ftest.txt ?f=/test.txt ?f=%2Ftest.txt ?f=asdf) The list goes on and on. Only file paths that were truly local to the script didn't throw the error. Again, I hate to use "100% safe", but I wasn't able to find something obvious to get past that.