# What is the security issue with my code?

Tags: php, security

A few years ago, I posted [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4205182/240613) to a question about a way, in PHP, to let the user pass in the URI the relative path to the file to download, while preventing directory traversal.

I got a few comments telling that the code is insecure, and a few downvotes (the most recent being today). Here's the code:

```
$path = $_GET['path'];
if (strpos($path, '../') !== false ||
    strpos($path, "..\\") !== false ||
    strpos($path, '/..') !== false ||
    strpos($path, '\..') !== false)
{
    // Strange things happening.
}
else
{
    // The request is probably safe.
    if (file_exists(dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $path))
    {
        // Send the file.
    }
    else
    {
        // Handle the case where the file doesn't exist.
    }
}
```

I reviewed the code again and again, tested it, and still can't understand what's the security issue it introduces.

The only hint I got in the comments is that `../` can be replaced by `%2e%2e%2f`. This is not an issue, since PHP will automatically transform it into `../`.

What is the problem with this piece of code? What could be the value of the input which would allow directory traversal or break something in some way?

Comment: `/etc/passwd` is still accepted

Comment: @SLaks: the URI http://example.com?path=/etc/passwd will give as a result something like `/home/demo-site/etc/passwd`, so no, it's not an issue.

Comment: Good question. And while it really itches I can't really find a fault yet, and it's really annoying the `/etc/passwd` suggestions that gets all the upvotes is here... while being wrong. Security is good, but throwing FUD around because of.. well because isn't very cool. I would still not be happy with this code (why no type checking? limit it to a certain whitelist, etc), but the fact there is all this kneejerking is bad as well

Comment: And how does this get -2? It is a serious and clear question, and by the +5-ed comment, one that lots of passer-by's get wrong, so not trivial at all for some...

Comment: Your code should start with (taking the path from the original question) `$path = '/whatever/path/' + $_GET['path'];` , then you can remove the traversals and ensure it's still in the right folder. (Although you may still have a problem with "%2e%2e%2f")

Comment: @SLaks It does appear on first glance that you are correct, but it is wrong as `/etc/password` will be appended to `/var/www/mysite` or whatever. You should delete your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just ran your code through [Burp intruder](http://portswigger.net/burp/help/intruder.html) and cannot find any way round it in this case.

It was probably down voted due to exploits against other/old technology stacks which employed a similar approach by blacklisting certain character combinations.

As you mention, the current version of PHP automatically URL decodes input, but there have been flaws where techniques such as double URL encoding (dot = `%252e`), 16 bit Unicode encoding (dot = `%u002e`), overlong UTF-8 Unicode encoding (dot = `%c0%2e`) or inserting a null byte (`%00`) could trick the filter and allow the server side code to interpret the path as the unencoded version once it had been given a thumbs up by the filter.

This is why it has set alarm bells ringing. Even though your approach appears to work here, generally it may not be the case. Technology is always changing and it is always best to err on the side of caution and use techniques that are immune to character set interpretations wherever possible such as using whitelists of known good characters that will likely to be always good, or using a file system function ([realpath](https://www.php.net/realpath) was mentioned in the linked answer) to verify that the actual path is the one you're expecting.

Answer (score 5):

There are lots of other possibilities that could slip through, such as:

```
.htaccess
some-secret-file-with-a-password-in-it.php
```

In other words, anything in the directory or a subdirectory would be accessible, including `.htaccess` files and source code. If anything in that directory or its subdirectories should not be downloadable, then that's a security hole.

Comment: All of the three paths would lead to files within the base directory. Given the context of the question/answer I quoted, I wouldn't consider it a security issue.

Comment: I don't see anything in the question (or the linked question and answer) indicating that all files in the directory are okay to download. If I missed something, please let me know. This is a potential security hole, however, so it is a valid answer to the question.

Comment: @Nanne I have revised my answer, and it actually says pretty much that.

Answer (score 3):

I can’t think of any case in which this should fail.

However, I don’t know how PHP’s `file_exists` is implemented internally and whether it has some currently unknown quirks. Just like [PHP had null byte related issues with some file system functions until PHP 5.3.4](http://php.net/security.filesystem.nullbytes).

So to play it safe, I’d rather like to check the already resolved path instead of blindly trusting PHP and – probably more important – my assumption, the four mentioned sequences are the only ones that can result in a path that is above the designated base directory. That’s why I would prefer [ircmaxell’s solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4205278/53114) to [yours](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4205182/53114).

Answer (score 2):

Blacklisting is a bad habit. You're better off with a whitelist (either on the literal strings allowed or on the characters allowed.)

```
if(preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9\-\_]*$/', $path) ) {
    // Yay
} else {
    // No
}
```

Or alternatively:

```
switch($path) {
    case 'page1':
    case 'page2':
        // ...
        break;
    default:
        $path = 'page1';
        break;
}

include $path;
```