# Are backspaces a concern in PHP file upload?

Tags: php, security, post

There is a php file in my server that is called when *authenticated* clients want to upload a file to their own server folder. Please note that it is a dev site, so there is no need to focus on possible issues like clients spamming the server etc. I get the **file path** from `$_POST['filePath']`, and the authenticated **username** `$_SERVER['REMOTE_USER']`.
Together they form the path where the file is created, like this:

```
users/$username/$filepath
```

Now the file path is the concern (as everything coming from the client usually is :) )

**Is it possible for the client to post backspaces in the file path string, and leave a way to modify the servers files?**

Here are a few examples:

- `test.txt` becomes `users/user/test.txt` (normal behavior)
- `foo/bar.log` becomes `users/user/foo/bar.log` (still normal behavior)
- `#8#8#8#8#8otheruser/important.txt` becomes `user/otheruser/important.txt` (#8 stands for a backspace, and this behavior is not wanted)
- `#8#8#8...http://this.domain.com/server.cfg` becomes `http://this.domain.com/server.cfg` (Definitely not wanted behavior)

Just to clarify my question, I want to know if this is possible, not a way to prevent it with, say, regexp.

Comment: Instead of backspaces, I would worry about ``..``, but +1 for thinking about these issues.

Comment: You need to sanitise the file path / file name the client is using. Using `basename($_POST['filePath'])` is a good start.

Comment: Using basename() removes the option for the client to create subfolders, as basename("dir/foo.txt") equals basename("foo.txt"). So are you saying it is possible to do that?

Comment: Have a look at [Preventing Directory Traversal in PHP but allowing paths](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4205278/53114).