# PHP - cms security

Tags: php, security, include, content-management-system

Would this be safe??

I would just like to hear if this "Cms" would be safe.
So people cant do example.com/../../../systemfile.conf

My index.php

```
<?php

$url= rtrim($_GET['page'], '/');

echo $url;

include_once "sites/$url";

?>
```

My .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.* - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)/? index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: No, this is not secure: `index.php?page=../../../systemfile.conf`

Comment: [Preventing Directory Traversal in PHP but allowing paths](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4205141/53114) might answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
include_once "sites/$url";
```

Should be changed to...

```
$inc='sites/' . realpath($url);
if (!is_readable($inc)) {
      header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
      exit;
}
include($inc);
```

as a *minimum*

Comment: -1 This won’t work. `realpath` already returns the canonical absolute path or `false`.

Comment: Ahh, true, I didn't say I'd *tested* it :) How about ...$stub=dirname(__FILE__).'/sites/'; $inc=realpath($stub.$url); if (substr($inc, 0, strlen($stub))!=$stub || ! is_radable($inc)) {

Comment: That would work and is basically what [@ircmaxell suggested on *Preventing Directory Traversal in PHP but allowing paths*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4205278/53114).

Answer (score -1):

I think that the answer to this would be no. The person may still be able to access system files, and the method seems quite worthless. Why not use cURL or something like it to access the page. It's safer but not the safest. But your script won't work in the first place considering,

```
include_once "sites/$url";
```

Should be changed to,

```
include_once "sites/" . $url;
```

So your script doesn't start sending users to "/sites/$url". You could do this if you want to be secure:

```
if(isset($_GET['pageid'])) {
    if($_GET['pageid']=='1') {
         include_once 'page1.php';
    }
}
```

You could make a new `$_GET['pageid']==` check for every page you need to send the user to.

Comment: Would this fix the problem?

Comment: Honestly if you're trying to load page content using PHP, you should store the content in a database, then print it out using PHP. Anything allowing the user to enter a file name in a GET/POST request should be considered unsafe.

Comment: I cant do that. I need to exute php scripts from my sites

Comment: I'm going to edit my answer with a suggestion right now.

Comment: Thanks ;D --> ignore "6 more to go"

Comment: Edited, hope you find it useful.

Comment: There's better ways to do this.

Comment: I'm all ears Half Crazed