# Protect Admin Folder htaccess recording to the session

Tags: php, .htaccess, session

This is the index.php file

```
<?php 
session_start();
if($_SESSION['login_success'] != "login_success")
{
header('Location: ../');
}
?>
```

I want to protect other files in the same folder from Downloading and Accessing
Maybe Something like htaccess file check if the session is true too

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to secure admin folder php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24617799/how-to-secure-admin-folder-php)