# easiest way to disallow ../ in php mkdir

Tags: php, string, directory, filesystems

Not a duplicate of [Preventing Directory Traversal in PHP but allowing paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205141/preventing-directory-traversal-in-php-but-allowing-paths/4205278#4205278) since my problem is in creating a DIR. Named question only works for comparing two already existing files/folders (as made obvious from this question [php realpath() returns a blank string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29419037/php-realpath-returns-a-blank-string)).

---

I have a PHP script that creates a folder based on a users name input.

What is the easiest way to deny the user from creating folders up/back in the structure as he could by typing for example "../../folderName" for the folder name?

I could sanitize the users string and remove slashes and/or dots, but is that a 100% safe way of doing it?

```
        //compile path to create
        $fPath = $path.$parent.'/'.$name;

        //create the folder
        if (!mkdir($fPath)) {
            //setup response json
            $resp = array();
            $resp['success'] = 0;
            $resp['message'] = "Error: Failed to create folder, check permissions on filesystem.";
        }
        else {

            //setup response json
            $resp = array();
            $resp['success'] = 1;
            $resp['message'] = "Folder successfully created in ".$fPath;

        }

        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($resp);
```

Comment: this is a very good example to prevent directory traversal http://stackoverflow.com/a/4205278/3859027

Comment: @Ghost Congrats on the 1k php *gold* badge ;-) that'll help speed things up.

Comment: @Fred-ii- trusty handy golden hammer :) i've also used that good answer in one of my projects

Comment: While the question you mention works well in comparing two existing files/folders, realpath() will not work to compare a basepath to the in-part user-supplied path where he/she wants to create a file/folder. Realpath will return false if supplied with a path to a not-yet existing object.