# File name sanitation for deleting via web

Tags: security, web-applications

If we have a web page that able to read or delete file (based on name) inside certain folder, for example: `'public/upload/'`, what kind of filtering we must use to prevent security issues?

For example in Ruby/Sinatra:

```
file_name = params[:file_name]
base_dir = 'public/upload/'
# prevent user from entering ../../../../../etc/passwd or any other things
file_name.gsub!('../','') 
File.delete "#{base_dir}/#{file_name}"
```

Is it enough?

Comment: Test it with these: http://security.stackexchange.com/a/96991/8340

Answer (score 1):

This kind of filtering is always error prone. However, something that could work, but which I cannot say is bulletproof, would be this:

[Preventing Directory Traversal in PHP but allowing paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205141/preventing-directory-traversal-in-php-but-allowing-paths)

Ruby has something like php's "realpath" afaik.

OWASP also has bit on how to prevent path traversal:
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/File_System#Path_traversal

Along with examples of how path traversal can be exploited:
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Path_Traversal