# PHP: readfile() corrupted download when using & (Ampersand)

Tags: php

I want to make a pdf down-loadable which can't be directy accessed by an url.

This is how the link would look like

```
<a href="getFile.php?file=myfile.pdf" >Myfile</a>
```

and that is **getFile.php**

```
<?php

  $file=$_GET['file'];

  // Check if file really exists:
  $files = array_diff(scandir('/www/secretPlace/'), array('.', '..'));
  $show = (in_array($file,$files)) ? true : false;
  if(!$show) exit();

  header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $file . '"');
  readfile( '/www/secretPlace/' . $file);
```

This works fine, as long as the pdf name does not include the `&` symbol. 
If I try

```
<a href="getFile.php?file=myfile & other stuff.pdf" >My Special File</a>
```

I would be able to download a file with the name, but I cant open it with a pdf reader. All programs tell me that the file is corrupted. How can I get open pdfs with readfile that have a `&` symbol in their name?

Comment: Never pass user input in function; If you do so user can download any file from your server;

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 I have added a check if the file is actually in the directory. Do you think its save now? Otherwise I am thinking about using http://stackoverflow.com/a/4205278/2311074.

Comment: No need to add `foreach` loop simply use `in_array()` to check;

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 thank you for the good advice. I changed that.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is vulnerable to **Path Traversal** attacks. I highly suggest you to specifically tell which files a user can download.

To your question (updated),

I'd suggest that you store the filenames (encoding is not neccessary) in a database, then each row would have a separate ID. You would make a page, let's say `/download/1234` for `ID 1234` , so you would automatically know which file it belongs to, not having to mess with special characters breaking the URI string. The URL structure can be configured in `.htaccess`, `/download/[1-9][0-9]*` pointing to that PHP page you included in your question, where you should handle all this. Then you would fetch the filename from the database, do a `glob()` check to see whether it exists, and start user download with `Content-Disposition`.

If you don't prefer the database solution, you need to encode special characters in the URI string (especially `&` as you mentioned), or write a function that parses the URI string by hand and not rely on `$_GET`, which splits the text at `&` and `=` while rendering.

To the extended question on security side:

I can provide filenames for which this turns true even if they shouldn't match.

```
if($pdf == $file) $show = true;
```

If you use three equal signs, it's way better, but still might be vulnerable to C null byte injection. So the suggestion here, as always, is to whitelist input instead of blacklisting (in this case `..`)

Comment: Do you suggest that I should make a page for each individual pdf? Because I am looking for a dynamical solution. I also added a check to my **getFile.php** to make sure that the file actually exists in the folder (just 1 sec before I saw your answer), so I think its not vulnerable to **Path Traversal** anymore, right?

Comment: This is a dynamic enough solution, if you do it with `.htaccess` the right way. You have to make one single PHP page.

Comment: It is still vulnerable to specific injections (CR, LF, null-byte). (As an advice, you never blacklist bad input, you always whitelist good). If you want to make a specific download directory available, just use `glob` to read filenames and whitelist them.

Comment: I don't see how my approach is vulnerable to a null byte injection, because I am doing the whitelist approach.

Comment: `$pdf = "abc.pdf"; $file="abc.pdf\0../../../../etc/passwd";` They might equal.

Comment: Just please believe me, this is my job :)

Comment: Okay. Thanks for your effort. But I still have 2 questions: 1) I don't completely understand your answer to my main question - are you basicly saying, that I should avoid the function `readfile` and save the content of the pdf in some php page that I somehow have to dynamically create? And then with .htacces I have to map a pdf filename to this dynamicaly created php that cointains the pdf in a variable?

Comment: 2) You said `I highly suggest you to specifically tell which files a user can download.` and when I iterate through all possible filenames in the folder and compare them with the userinput `$file` then you say this is still not enough. How should I do it then? I mean even if I had  a handwritten array with allowed filenames, in the end I need to compare it with the userinput, or nor? I am not questioning your competence, I just want to understand what I have to do. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Sorry about that, I didn't update the answer since you updated yours, but here it is. I proposed a more suitable solution.

Answer (score 1):

It did not work because when using

```
<a href="getFile.php?file=myfile & other stuff.pdf" >My Special File</a>
```

then

```
$file=$_GET['file'];
```

has only the value `myfile`. One needs to decode the url like this:

```
<a href="getFile.php?file=<?php echo urlencode('myfile & other stuff.pdf'); ?>" >My Special File</a>
```

The security white-list approach could be replaced by the maybe more secure method explained in https://stackoverflow.com/a/4205278/2311074