# advise on securing php from directory traversal

Tags: php

I have the following script to secure a page from directory traversal attack:

```
function secure_file_path($file_path){
    preg_match('/(wp\-content\/themes|wp\-content\/plugins)/', $file_path, $matches);
    if(count($matches) > 0){
        preg_match('/(\/*\.{2}\/*)/', $file_path, $dir_traversal);
        if(count($dir_traversal) > 0){
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

`secure_file_path()` was called before I am running `DirectoryIterator` to check if there is a string of `wp-content/plugins` or `wp-content/themes` and also check for `..`. But is this secure enough?

PS: example input of `$file_path` could be `/home/linux_user/www/wp-content/themes/ltru/../../../../../../etc/passwd`

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205141/preventing-directory-traversal-in-php-but-allowing-paths

Comment: the [`open_basedir`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir) is safest. Set it with `ini_set()` (5.3+)